# [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: this.method is not a function" - Error shows only on my console but working as expected on browser

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I can't tell what I'm not doing properly because everything seems to be working as expected on my browser. The problem I have is that whenever I access this component the second time and either create, update or delete, It gives me this error. But without using router-link to access the component, there is no error on my console. How can I tackle this?

On my app.js, I have this function which is supposed to init the table

```
const Pag = function(){
    let a = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable({

        lengthChange: !1,
        buttons: ["copy", "print", "pdf"],
        language: {
            paginate: {
                previous: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'>",
                next: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'>"
            }
        },
        order: [],
        columnDefs: [ {
            'targets': [0], /* column index [0,1,2,3]*/
            'orderable': false, /* true or false */
        }],
        drawCallback: function() {
            $(".dataTables_paginate > .pagination").addClass("pagination-rounded")
        }
    });
     a.buttons().container().appendTo("#datatable-buttons_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)"), $("#alternative-page-datatable").DataTable({
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        drawCallback: function() {
            $(".dataTables_paginate > .pagination").addClass("pagination-rounded")
        }
    })

}

window.Pag = Pag;
```

FYI, the error refers to the this.initTable() in the loadEs() method

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
<script>
import JobRoute from "../nav/JobRoute";

export default {
    name: 'EmploymentStatus',

    components:{
        JobRoute, 
    },


    //every component must return something
    data(){
        return {
            editMode: false,
            eStatus:{},
            esForm: new Form({
                'estatus_id': '',
                'name': '',
                'comment': '',
            }),

        }
    },
    methods: {
        createEstatus: function(){
            this.$Progress.start();
                this.esForm.post('/api/employmentstatus')
                    .then(response => {
                        Fire.$emit('esCreated');
                        $('#esModal').modal('hide');
                        Toast.fire({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Employment status create Successful'
                        });

                    })
                    .catch(errors => {
                        //this.errors = errors.response.data.errors;
                    });
            this.$Progress.finish();
        },

        initTable: function(){
            return new Pag() //initialize table
        },

        loadEs(){
            axios.get('/api/employmentstatus')
                .then ( response => {
                    this.eStatus = response.data.data; 
                }).then( ()=>{
                    this.$nextTick(function() { this.initTable() })
                })
                .catch(function (error) { 
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },

    },

    mounted() {

        this.loadEs();
        Fire.$on('esCreated', () => {
            $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable().destroy();
            this.loadEs();
        }) 

    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.initTable = null;
        delete this.initTable()

    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: You're setting `this.initTable` to `null` in the `beforeDestroy` hook and then you immediately try to invoke it in the `delete this.initTable()` line. It's not a function a that point anymore, it's `null`, thus the error. To delete that property, just do `delete this.initTable`, although I'm also not sure why you're attempting to delete that method.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error, If I don't delete the method and i route to another component which also initialized the same method, it shows an error that datatable cannot e reinitialized. @thanksd

Comment: From within the nextTick callback try to print out `this` or `this.editMode` to console so you can see if you have the right context.

Comment: @ege thanks so much, this.editMode only returns true when the edit button for a record is clicked. on my console if I print this or this.edtMode, it's all good

Comment: @codervine well, then I will agree with @thanksd above. It is because the `initTable` method is deleted. It literally doesn't exist anymore. Change your code to counter this behaviour

Comment: @ege I delete the initTable method and instantiate it again once a create, edit or delete is performed on the page. If I don't delete it and I try accessing another page with a datatable, it alerts that Datatable is already initialized. However with the way it is, on the browser, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try `import Vue from 'vue'` and then `Vue.nextTick(...)`

Answer (score 0):

is this just a case of `this` inside the chained promise function being different from `this` in your component? You could try:

```
    loadEs(){
        let self = this; //<---added
        axios.get('/api/employmentstatus')
            .then ( response => {
                this.eStatus = response.data.data; 
            }).then( ()=>{
                this.$nextTick(function() { self.initTable() }) //<--changed
            })
            .catch(function (error) { 
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
```

Comment: Thanks BryanOfEarth but the error has changed to Error in nextTick: "TypeError: self.initTable is not a function"